# rails 3 associations trying to limit return data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I fully admit this is user inexperience but here is my problem

I have 2 models that relate by

```
     class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team


  class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
```

What I want to do is display all users that belong to the same team as the logged in user. so basically select from user there team_id = my team_id

I was not sure if I could / should do this in the controller or the view but I could not get either to work.

in my controller I have this which returns all users for all teams

```
 @users = User
```

which is SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`

I can also use my current_user method which returns info on my current user

```
 @users = current_user.team
```

which is SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`id` = 3

I dont know how to get a list of all users where team_id = current_user team_id?

Also would like to know if its best to try this in the controller or out in the view?

Thanks

Comment: `current_user.team.users` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @apneadiving using `curent_user.team.users` would return the list of users. But I just wanted to advise you to wrap that behavior in a method.
So for instance you could have in your `User` model something like :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :team

  def coworkers
    team.users
  end
end
```

And then in your controller you could do

```
def an_action
  @coworkers = current_user.coworkers
end
```

Finally in your view you could loop through this list to display them

```
@coworkers.each do |coworker|
  ...
```